# Joomla-Tree-menu consisting of categories and entries

Tags: plugins, joomla, navigation

I'm searching a plugin for displaying a tree-structure. The first level should be the category names and the second one the entries.

e.g.
- Australia 2012
-- Day 1 (arrival)
-- Day 2 (this and that)
- Kanada 2013
-- Day 1 (arrival)
-- Day 2 (departure)

etc.
where "Australia 2012" and "Kanada 2013" are categories and "Day X" are entries.

Is there a plugin or even a native feature for this purpose? I'm using Joomla 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

there are two modules in the joomla core that might fit your purpose, but you most certainly have to override the layout of the module to make it display like you want to:

- /modules/mod_articles_category
- /modules/mod_articles_categories

To override the layout, look [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) or [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/alternative-layouts-for-modules/) (there are lots of tutorials for this).

regards Jonas